# Localized Date Format for Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, date, localization

I'm using a custom field, formatted with "dd-mm-yyyy". I would like to use it with the Date Format defined in the Dashboard settings.

It seems alright in English with

```
get_option('date_format');
```

Or manually in French with

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$date_local = strftime("%d-%m-%Y",$date->format('U'));
```

But is there a way to use the localized date format of wordpress? I can't find how to give the date as an argument to

```
the_date()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I found the answer right after posting:

```
date_i18n(get_option('date_format') ,$timestamp);
```

it was in an example [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n)