# Modify Date Format to German

Tags: date, options, date-time

I basically need to change the date format to german date format all over the WordPress site and I succeed it by changing the date time settings from the WordPress admin panel.

> **Settings » General**  :
>
> **Date Format** - Custom : j. F Y
>
> eg : 5. July 2016

However I need to change the month names to german as well.

> eg : 5. Juli 2016

How should I do that ?

Comment: I can remeber a similar question being asked here a long way back. Use the site search, you should pick it up somewhere

Comment: to be honest I couldn't find similar one, but I found this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/localized-date-format-for-custom-field
however it doesn't help for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added the following code to child theme function and it works,

```
add_filter('the_time', 'modify_date_format');
function modify_date_format(){
    $month_names = array(1=>'Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember');
    return get_the_time('j').'. '.$month_names[get_the_time('n')].' '.get_the_time('Y');
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Great solution if you are not using German as the Wordpress language, many thanks!

Comment: this solution is not working for me ? I have added above code in function.php

Answer (score 6):

WordPress has a special function for translating dates, called [`date_i18n`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n). General usage:

```
echo date_i18n( $dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp, $gmt);
```

Supposing you have German as your site's language this would be:

```
echo date_i18n( 'j. F Y', false, false);
```

You can also import the time format from the admin settings, like this:

```
echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), false, false);
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm not using the german as site's language.

Comment: In that case, you can't use WP's built in translation module. Your own function would be a fine solution then.

Answer (score 3):

go to admin follow 2 simple steps

1. Date Format - Custom : j. F Y
2. Change Site Language which one you want change and then save

[image]

Comment: I have tried this solution before, due to some reason the site language is not changing to German.

Comment: @JanithChinthana, you need to ensure the language locale is installed on your server. See https://askubuntu.com/a/76106/682407 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use locale in `wp-config.php` de_DE, language settings depends on admin panel language, it is possible to separate site language and admin panel language. 
Also in wp-content>languages look for `de_DE.po`, use search.