# WordPress change post date format from english to japanese

Tags: php, date

For my **WordPress V-4.9.1** I want to change the **Post date** format from **English to Japanese** like `DECEMBER 29, 2017 to 2017年12月29日`. I know it is possible if I change the WordPress admin language but without changing the language it is possible?

Please let me know if anyone know solution or any plugin with the help of it is possible?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Without editing theme template...  i don't think there is any filter hook to do that. I think you need to override  the theme template.

Comment: @BikashWaiba I have tried this also but unable to success tried solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231480/124298

Comment: If you want to display post in japanese, you can try plugin like Polylang which help you to do a multilingual website.

Comment: @mmm I don't want multilingual website. I want website in only 1 language i.e. Japanese But admin panel in english.

Comment: it's what is called a multilingual website then polylang can help you to do that.